# Парсинг файла через python

Tags: python

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста. Нужно с помощью модуля argparse спарсить входящий текстовый файл.
К примеру номера телефонов которые кончаются на 001 записать в другой файл 001.тхт, а если на 1хх, то 100.тхт
в текстовом файле номера прописаны словарем(8хххх:имя_фамилия)
Тобишь при вводе программе аргументов -100 записываются все номера с 1хх, если - 000 то 0хх и тд

Answer (score 1):

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Zapis v slovar')
parser.add_argument('--key', action="store", dest="key", required=True)
```

Вот вам пример, где в командную строку подается `--key 100`, например, тогда `args.key` присваивается значение `100`. `dest` определяет присваивание. 
Другие возможности подробно расписаны в библиотеке.

Далее, получив значение в `args.key`, например, парсите ключи словаря, и находя необходимое значение в конце номера телефона - перезаписываете в новый файл.